# Define styles inside component but do not inline them [React]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I like the idea of having everything inside React component (including styles).
But I do not like the idea of inline styles (1-duplications, 2-heavy mess on Elements tab).

Is there any existing way to define styles inside component but do not have to inline them?

I mean in dev and production environments. Never inline them.

Kind of: still using CSS, but isolated to one component...

Complete requirements:

1. Styles defined **inside** component
2. **no inline**
3. support **preudo-classes/elements**
4. support **@-rules**

Comment: Do you use something such as Webpack ?

Comment: @Pcriulan I use Meteor... I know there is a 'js-next/react-style' which somehow works with Webpack.. but you have to build your project so styles will be translated to CSS classes, and it will still inline in dev environment, right?

Comment: I mean, to build your project ?

Comment: @Pcriulan Well.. Meteor builds my project himself :)

Comment: Meteor does not allow you to write something like `require('css/my_component.css')` in your component js file ?

Comment: @Pcriulan Not sure. But again, it means you should have external .css file? I would like to have my styles inside component..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88603/discussion-between-artin-and-pcriulan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [jss](https://github.com/jsstyles/jss), it has also [react integration](https://github.com/jsstyles/react-jss)

Comment: Yep, I've tried [several solutions](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium/blob/master/docs/comparison/README.md) and looks like 'react-jss' is exactly what I need. Going to mark this as an answer when [@-rules will be supported](https://github.com/jsstyles/jss/issues/46) :P

Answer (score 0):

I've done this by having a `.sass` file that I import in the component's jsx file. I then put a class on the outermost div of the component, and namespace everything in the `.sass` file by that class.

Comment: Thanks, but ... doesn't it mean that you define your styles _outside_ the component? How is this approach better than having separate .css file (excluding namespacing that you should do manually) ?

Comment: I suppose it does, but by importing the css file in the component's jsx file, you're insuring that the css is only used and loaded when the component itself is being used. This would be different from having a global css file where all of it is loaded every time, regardless of if you're using the component. I like this approach because it also makes finding the css for your component really easy.

Comment: yep, I see. actually I have my styles in .css, so each component have its personal .css file which lies next to it, but that requires me to move .jsx and .css to separate folder. While I want everything encapsulated to one file...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, made [Style It](http://github.com/buildbreakdo/style-it/) because I wanted to just write plaintext CSS and not go through the object literal syntax.

Fulfills all of your requirements and some. No build step or anything to configure, automagically scopes to keep your selectors out of the global CSS namespace, XSS safe by default, tiny, and flash of unstyled content (FOUC) free.

`npm install style-it --save`

**Functional Syntax** ([JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y2pnqh9e/49/))

```js
import React from 'react';
import Style from 'style-it';

class Intro extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return Style.it(`
      #heart {
        position: relative;
        width: 100px;
        height: 90px;
      }
      #heart:before,
      #heart:after {
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        left: 50px;
        top: 0;
        width: 50px;
        height: 80px;
        background: red;
        -moz-border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
        border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
        -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
        -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
        -o-transform-origin: 0 100%;
        transform-origin: 0 100%;
      }
      #heart:after {
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
        -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
        -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
        -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
        transform-origin :100% 100%;
      }
    `,
      <div id="heart" />
    );
  }
}

export default Intro;
```

**JSX Syntax** ([JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y2pnqh9e/50/))

```js
import React from 'react';
import Style from 'style-it';

class Intro extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Style>
      {`
        #heart {
          position: relative;
          width: 100px;
          height: 90px;
        }
        #heart:before,
        #heart:after {
          position: absolute;
          content: "";
          left: 50px;
          top: 0;
          width: 50px;
          height: 80px;
          background: red;
          -moz-border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
          border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
          -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
          -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
          -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
          transform: rotate(-45deg);
          -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
          -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
          -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
          -o-transform-origin: 0 100%;
          transform-origin: 0 100%;
        }
        #heart:after {
          left: 0;
          -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
          -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
          -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
          -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
          -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
          -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
          -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
          transform-origin :100% 100%;
        }
     `}

      <div id="heart" />
    </Style>
  }
}

export default Intro;
```

Heart example pulled from [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)